# C++ : rebind variable of generic type

Tags: c++, generics, memory-management, binding, value-type

## Re-use heap memory for generic types by rebinding variables.

**What I want to do:**

```cpp
template <typename T> //unconstrained type
//...
{
  //in some complex procedural logic
  T rebindable = .../*r-value*/;

  //...
  //some procedure dependent case:
  T rebindable = .../*different r-value*/; //rebind (I am aware this does not work)
}
```

**Why this is a question worth asking:**

Many procedural algorithms maintain and continually operate on memory throught their scope.
Sometimes it is logically nessacary to completely replace one of these values, programmatically that means deconstruction and construction, potentially an indeterminate number of times (rebinding).

Typically this would be overcome by leveraging itteration, for example an implimentation of a [smart-bisection root finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi) over potentially unassignable numeric types.

However some more complicated procedural algorithms may not be easilly written functionally, especially if rebinding is determined by procedural state.

Hence programmatically implimenting rebinding could be increadibly useful for generic algorithms.

### Unsatisfactory answers

(This is by no means an attack on anyone or their answers)

**Unique_ptr:**

```cpp
template <typename T> //still unconstrained (which is a plus)
//...
{
  auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>{.../*dangling reference (T*)*/};

  //...
  ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>{.../*different dangling reference*/};
}
```

This solves the problem of not constraining the type, however the memory being used isnt heap memory.

**Assignment:**

```cpp
template <typename T>
  requires std::assignable_from<T, T> //type constraint!
//...
{
  T assignable = .../*r-value*/;

  //...
  assignable = .../*different r-value*/;
}
```

Whilst this is on heap it comes at the cost of constraining the type.

**Placement new:**

```cpp
template <std::copy_constructible T> //type constraint!
//...
{
  T assignable = .../*r-value*/;

  //...
  assignable.~T();
  new (&assignable) T {.../*different r-value*/};
}
```

By deconstructing and constructing again with assignment new the value is rebound, however this still has an associated type constraint.

Comment: @mark_s Please stop editing my question to suit your personal formatting requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Rebind using placement new

The last example using placement new does not require the associated type constraint!

The expression `T t = r-value;` does not call the constructor, and in the same way, the expression `new (&t) T {r-value};` does not call the constructor either.

**placement new bypasses the constructor with r-values**

here is an example of this behaviour: (compiles on GCC)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

struct C
{
    int n;
    static C make_new(int n) {return C{n};}
    ~C() = default;
    C(int n): n(n) {}
    C(const C &) = delete;
    C(C&&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
void inline rebind(T& re_bin_ref, T&& val) {
    re_bin_ref.~T();
    new (&re_bin_ref) T {val};
}

template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
void inline emplace_rebind(T& re_bin_ref, TArgs&&... args) {
    re_bin_ref.~T();
    new (&re_bin_ref) T {std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...};
}

template <typename T>
void inline procedural_rebind(T& re_bin_ref, auto f) {
    re_bin_ref.~T();
    new (&re_bin_ref) T { f() };
}

int main()
{
    
    std::cout << "\nREBINDING:\n";
    C re_bin = C::make_new(0);
    std::cout << "init: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;
    
    //...
    
    re_bin.~C();
    new (&re_bin) C {C{1}};
    std::cout << "pr-value: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;
    
    //...
    
    //re_bin.~C();
    //new (&re_bin) C {std::move<C>(C::make_new(2))}; //requires C&&
    //std::cout << "x-value: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;
    
    //...
    
    //rebind(re_bin, C::make_new(3)); //requires C&&
    //std::cout << "explicit rebind: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;

    //...
    
    emplace_rebind(re_bin, 4);
    std::cout << "explicit emplace rebind: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;

    //...

    procedural_rebind(re_bin, [](){return C{5};});
    std::cout << "explicit pr-value procedural rebind: " << re_bin.n << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Full file on GodBolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/cz7Y6qzbe

Comment: `re_bin.~C();` UB starts here I think - calling the destructor of an automatic (on the stack) variable - this is only valid if `C re_bin` was allocated by placement new see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor _"...Note that calling a destructor directly for an ordinary object, such as a local variable, invokes undefined behavior when the destructor is called again, at the end of scope...."_  I think the 1st allocation needs to be a placement new.

Comment: `T t = r-value; does not call the constructor`,  I'm not sure what you mean here; code like this in general calls a constructor (a move constructor).

Comment: @RichardCritten It's only UB if the destructor when going out of scope is called before a new object starts its lifetime in the same space. It would be UB if an exception is thrown before the placement new occurs

Comment: @AndyG If it is assigned to a prvalue, the result object becomes `t`, and there is no copy/move constructor called

Comment: You still apply a constraint that the prvalue you "rebind" to has to be noexcept, and that the move constructor noexcept if you use the `rebind` function. Also you have the constraint that `T` contains no reference or const-qualified data members, otherwise you have to access `re_bin` via `*std::launder(std::addressof(re_bin))` everytime (or bind the result of `new`, in which case you can just use a different variable name)

Comment: @Artyer am checking The Standard - cppreference does not have an allowance for the object being recreated in place (or I just can't see it).  I agree with you that it could/should be safe but am looking for definitive reference for an object not created by placement new.

Comment: @Artyer: There is still construction happening in that case; it's just that `t` gets constructed directly instead of a temporary being put into the right hand side.

Comment: @RichardCritten this isnt an issue because immediately after each explicit destructor call a new instance is constructed.

Comment: @AndyG , I have edited the example code in my answer to better demonstrate the behaviour I am on about! Try it in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: @RichardCritten: OP is correct, refer to basic.life: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8

Comment: @Artyer I have just linked the GodBolt file that I used to verify all of this, I reccomend you have a look at it, its very interesting: https://godbolt.org/z/cz7Y6qzbe

Answer (score 1):

A type like `std::optional` could do the trick, if you're willing to pay for the extra boolean on the stack.

```
template <typename T> //unconstrained type
void func()
{
    //in some complex procedural logic
    std::optional<T> rebindable;
    rebindable.emplace(/*r-value*/);

    //...
    //some procedure dependent case:
    rebindable.reset();
    rebindable.emplace(/*different r-value*/);
}
```

I think you'll need it to be move constructible since you have to go through the emplace function.

Comment: I feel like that, as an idea, is a lot cleaner. If I have to do this I will probably impliment a `rebindable<T>` class to do this.